# Visual basic not adding number together from textbox's?

Tags: vb.net

So I have this program. It calculates the sale price of an item and displays the tax, subtotal, discount percent, which all works fine. The thing im trying to do is show 3 more textbox that accumulate the subtotal, discount amount, and the average discount.

Everytime I type anything in, the textboxs that are supposed to be accumulating are just displaying what the other boxs say, basically duplicating the boxs

```
Dim numberOfInvoices As Integer
Dim totalOfInvoices As Decimal
Dim invoiceAverage As Decimal

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim subtotal As Decimal = CDec(txtEnterSubtotal.Text)
    Dim discountPercent As Decimal = 0.25D
    Dim discountAmount As Decimal = Math.Round(subtotal * discountPercent, 2)
    Dim invoiceTotal As Decimal = subtotal - discountAmount
    Dim enterSubtotal As Decimal = Val(txtEnterSubtotal.Text)
    Dim accumDiscount As Decimal = Val(txtAccumDiscAmount.Text)
    Dim avgDiscount As Decimal = Val(txtAccumDiscAmount.Text)
    Dim accumSubTotal As Decimal = Val(txtAccumSubtotal.Text)

    txtSubtotal.Text = FormatCurrency(subtotal)
    txtDiscountPercent.Text = FormatPercent(discountPercent, 1)
    txtDiscountAmount.Text = FormatCurrency(discountAmount)
    txtTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(invoiceTotal)

    numberOfInvoices += 1
    totalOfInvoices += invoiceTotal
    invoiceAverage = totalOfInvoices / numberOfInvoices

    txtNumberOfInvoices.Text = numberOfInvoices.ToString
    txtTotalOfInvoices.Text = FormatCurrency(totalOfInvoices)
    txtInvoiceAverage.Text = FormatCurrency(invoiceAverage)

    'below is where I'm trying to accumulate everything entered....
    txtAccumSubtotal.Text = FormatCurrency(accumSubTotal + subtotal)
    txtAccumDiscAmount.Text = FormatCurrency(accumDiscount + discountAmount)

    If avgDiscount = 0 Then
        txtAvgDiscAmount.Text = FormatCurrency(discountAmount)
    ElseIf avgDiscount > 0 Then
        txtAvgDiscAmount.Text = FormatCurrency(avgDiscount / numberOfInvoices)
    End If

    txtEnterSubtotal.Text = ""
    txtEnterSubtotal.Select()
    'This is a comment
End Sub
```

Comment: Which textboxes do you expect what in? (IE, which 3 should we be looking at?)

Comment: i commented the line, the 3 textboxes underneath the comment line is where you should focus

Comment: I think you should use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the `txtAccumSubtotal.Text` line, and inspect the four variables being passed to `FormatCurrency()`. If some of them are set to 0, that would explain no change occurring.

Comment: In some cases, SubTotal for instance, if there is no value in `txtAccumSubtotal` the result will just be `substotal`  hard to tell without knowing if AccumSub has values that carry over from somewhere else or if there is more than one thing/trans.  iF the `Accum???` TBs are empty, the value will be 0.

Comment: Ok, so I changed my code and everything works if i DONT FORMAT CURRENCY. As soon as I try and format it, everything stops working...

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my previous post, I was wrong.  I found the problem.

`VAL()` on a percent or currency field will return 0.  You have to take the "$" and "%" out of your string to do a `VAL()`.

Comment: You got it, as I was typing. Funny

Comment: is there a way to remove the "$" and "%" programatically and then re-add it after I calculate it?

Comment: Explore the [decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx) with the IFormatProvider and NumberStyles parameters. Remove any reference to old VB6 functions and use the more powerful NET methods